Special set of numbers
There is something special about this set of numbers. Can you find what it is?
14 27 53 56 74 104 123 140 167 177
Hints:

 Note the mathematics tag.


 This is a set, so order doesn't matter.


 Each number on their own is not special, but when they are together they become special.


 I like primes.


No pattern or sequence tag?

They're the roots to f(x) = x^10 - 935 x^9 + 378558 x^8 - 87046462 x^7 + 12529587641 x^6 - 1173114030567 x^5 + 71863086225112 x^4 - 2819641162448948 x^3 + 67035083609539248 x^2 - 858006858024062208 x + 4394845783011640320.

rot13(Gur qvtvgf rvtug naq avar ner zvffrq).

@ᵍʰᗣˢᵗ they're also the root of f(x) = 0

Obvious first check: it is not in the OEIS.

@Alex Ravsky also lim_{n→∞} ∑_{i=1}^n f'(xᵢ*) ∆x = 0, where ∆x = (b−a)/n and xₙ = a+n∆x. Kind of a simple puzzle, ngl. Not sure why they bothered posting.

@Nautilus no. I don't believe those tags apply here.

Factorization was one thing I tried, but with OP's latest hint and Zomulgustar's suspicion I came to the conclusion:
The special thing about this specific set of numbers is...

 if the sum of any two numbers from the set is an odd number, it's a prime. 

 Easiest to show in a table (Actually, it's symmetric by the diagonal, i.e. half of the table would be enough).
 The yellow marked numbers are all primes: 



if and only if :-)

This is probably part of it but I imagine there will be more to it as there are many sets which will satisfy this property.

@hexomino of course, there could be more behind it, but I guess that's probably one of the simplest descriptions. If you just take one number with ending 1 it would not work anymore. OP needs to tell if there is hidden more inside.

Yes that's the answer, well done! In fact all the numbers in yellow are distinct (ignoring the symmetry). There is nothing more to it. I will post another puzzle involving more unique sets of this type.

New puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/129532/special-set-of-11-numbers

Not sure how to 'prove' other than exhaustive checking (in fact, I'm genuinely curious what about the set made me think of trying it), but it turns out the pairwise sums, differences, products, and ratios of the elements are all unique.

You are on the right track, but this is not the intended answer. There is something even more special.

Moreover, rot13(hfvat gur qrpbzcbfvgvbaf bs gur ahzoref vagb gur cebqhpg bs cevzr ahzoref, vg vf vg rnfl gb purpx gung cebqhpgf bs qvfgvapg fhofrgf bs ahzoref ner nyfb qvfgvapg). On the other hand, rot13(gur fhzf bs qvfgvapg fhofrgf bs ahzoref pna or rdhny).

14 + 56 = 70  = 123 - 53, so not unique across operations
