Special set of 11 numbers
Can you find a set of 11 positive integers such that the product of every pair of numbers plus one is a distinct prime? So the set should generate 55 distinct primes. Computers are allowed.

If we

repeatedly write the next smallest number such that its product with every other number listed so far is a prime minus one,

we get

 A034881: 1, 2, 6, 18, 30, 270, 606, 123120, 888456, 23070450, 238550160, 8282903640, 72789145650, 15681266370000, 18216437241240, ...


That's brilliant! I wasn't actually aware of this sequence and spent days looking for these sets. I have accepted your answer, but if you feel like an extra challenge there is a solution where the maximum number is less than 20000.

But it does make me sad that such a naive greedy approach works
